# C# - Converting a list of Excel rows into a range

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# program I am creating as a parsing program. One section of the code pulls in a list of rows in an Excel file that do not have a particular value in a particular column. I was then going to use a foreach loop to loop through each of those rows and delete them, however it is taking quite a long time to cycle through each of those rows. And there are multiple tabs that I am needing to run this on.

So my thought was turning the list of Excel rows into a range and then just deleting that range. Is this possible to convert that list of rows into an Excel range? Below is the code snippet:

```
                XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(Path.Combine(Destination, fName) + ".xlsx");
                IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheet(SheetName);

                var range = ws.RangeUsed();
                var table = range.AsTable();

                var cell = table.HeadersRow().CellsUsed(c => c.Value.ToString() == ColName).FirstOrDefault();

                //Gets the column letter for use in next section
                string colLetter = cell.WorksheetColumn().ColumnLetter();

                //Create list of rows that DO NOT contain the inv number being searched
                //This is the list I would like to convert to a range to speed up the delete          
                List<IXLRow> deleterows = ws
                    .Column(colLetter)
                    .CellsUsed(c => c.Value.ToString() != i)
                    .Select(c => c.WorksheetRow()).ToList();

                //Deletes the header row so that isn't removed
                deleterows.RemoveAt(0);

                foreach (IXLRow x in deleterows)
                {
                    x.Delete();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now each iteration checks the value of the cell by accessing that cell in the file. That takes a lot of time.

[Read all the data on one sheet into an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Value_System_Object_) and do all the iteration in the array. That will be a magnitude faster.

Since you want to parse data, I suggest you use that array for any other operation you want to do and only write it back to a file when you are done. (If your result is stored in Excel again, make sure write the whole array at once as a Range).